# Rinkeby contracts deployment Error: Timeout

Tags: timeout, ethereum, truffle, metamask, nft

I was trying to follow this tutorial:

https://docs.opensea.io/docs/1-structuring-your-smart-contract

And even found this extremely helpful YouTube video to guide me:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lbXcvRx0o3Y&ab_channel=DanViau

But I've encountered a problem after installing and setting up everything I needed. The problem occured when I tried to deploy the contracts using this bash command:

```
truffle deploy --network rinkeby
```

The error message I got is:

```
Error: There was a timeout while attempting to connect to the network.
   Check to see that your provider is valid.
   If you have a slow internet connection, try configuring a longer timeout in your Truffle config. Use the networks[networkName].networkCheckTimeout property to do this.
at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\alonb\.nvm\versions\node\v12.22.5\bin\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\provider\index.js:56:1)
at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7)
```

It's not caused by slow internet connection - I know that because I have tried executing this command on 3 different WiFi connections, one at 200 Mb/s rate.

I have tried to change the truffle-config.js file and add a longer timeout threshold (like suggested [here](https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/if-you-have-a-slow-internet-connection-try-configuring-a-longer-timeout-in-your-truffle-config-use-the-networks-networkname-networkchecktimeout-property-to-do-this/5338)), but the only thing that changed was that the error message took much longer to appear.

Technical info - I'm using Git Bash, npm version 6.14.14, nvm version 0.38.0, node version 12.22.5.

Any suggestions? I'm lost.

Alon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is incredibly easy -

Instead of using just the relevant part of the Alchemy key:

40Oo3XScVabXXXX8sePUEp9tb90gXXXX

I used the whole URL:

https://eth-rinkeby.alchemyapi.io/v2/40Oo3XScVabXXXX8sePUEp9tb90gXXXX

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into this error when following the same tutorial.

I use Alchemy (not Infura), and the issue was my API_KEY.

In other tutorials I've followed, the scripts require the full alchemy API Key (ex. "https://eth-rinkeby.alchemyapi.io/v2/<**random-key**>").

So, when I was following this tutorial, that is what I supplied. And, I ran into the error you reported.

But when I reviewed the truffle.js script provided by the tutorial authors, I found this:

```
const rinkebyNodeUrl = isInfura
  ? "https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/" + NODE_API_KEY
  : "https://eth-rinkeby.alchemyapi.io/v2/" + NODE_API_KEY;
```

Thus, the script was producing:

```
rinkebyNodeUrl = https://eth-rinkeby.alchemyapi.io/v2/https://eth-rinkeby.alchemyapi.io/v2/<**random-key**>
```

...which is clearly wrong.

Thus, ensuring I set my API_KEY environment variable only to **random-key** and not https://eth-rinkeby.alchemyapi.io/v2/https://eth-rinkeby.alchemyapi.io/v2/<**random-key**>, my contract deployed successfully.

Also, make sure you have enough ETH in your wallet on the Rinkeby network. Faucets always seem to work for a little while then stop working, so do some Google searches to find one that is currently functional.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same experience but when using hardhat not truffle.My internet connection was ok,try switching from Git bash to terminal(CMD).Use a completely new terminal avoid Gitbash and powershell.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the function wrapper from provider inside the network configuration.

```
ropsten_infura: {
  provider: new HDWalletProvider({
    mnemonic: {
      phrase: mnemonic
    },
    providerOrUrl: `https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/${project_id}`,
    addressIndex
  }),
  network_id: 3
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The rinkbery network has been decommissioned. Use Goerli or Sepolia network. Update your truffle config add a section for goerli in networks. E.g

```
goerli: {
  provider: () =>
    new HDWalletProvider(
      mnemonic,
      `https://goerli.infura.io/v3/${INFURAKEY}`
    ),
  network_id: 5, // goerli's id
  gas: 4500000, // 
  gasPrice: 10000000000,
}
```

The run the command

```
truffle deploy --network goerli
```